# Bootstrap container margin stays after specifying zero

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want my right container elements to take up the full width of its column. I saw using chrome inspector that my bootstrap container automatically had right and left margins, so I specified for them to be at zero.

My left margin disappeared, but my right margin remains, even though it says in the inspector that there is zero margin, an obvious orange space is still there, attached to the container.

[You can see it here in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YTAH.png)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="bg-img">
  <div>
    <img class="logo" src="./images/logo.svg" alt="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-margin">
      <div class="col-lg-8 left-col">
        <img class="illu-img" src="./images/illustration-mockups.svg" alt="illustration-mockups">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 right-col">
        <h1>Build The Community Your Fans Will Love</h1>
        <h2>Huddle re-imagines the way we build communities. You have a voice, but so does your audience. 
          Create connections with your users as you engage in genuine discussion. </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: hsl(257, 40%, 49%);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.bg-img {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(./images/bg-desktop.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 4%; 
}

.logo {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.container {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.illu-img {
    width: 101%;
}
```

Comment: The orange part you talking about is not a margin, that exists because there is `max-width` property for `container` class.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! But I'm still lost as to how to fix it. I tried to change the max-width but it changes the width of the entire container, it doesn't extend the right one. I also don't know why it's not just taking the full width of the browser, since my browser is 1140px and it's the same value for the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, as I said earlier your problem exists because there is `max-width` property for `container` class. So to fix this you should override your `container`, `max-width` property just like this:

```css
.container {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  max-width: unset;
}
```

**Live demo:** [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/smalikss/pen/wvMpQQe)